# Order of volatile access is undefined in this statement

Tags: c, volatile

Имеются две volatile-переменные:

```
volatile uint32_t a;
volatile uint32_t b;
```

Они объявлены как volatile, потому что могут измениться как в основной программе, так и в обработчике прерывания, так и устройствами на системной шине (такими как DMA). Если обе переменные участвуют в одном выражении, например:

```
uint32_t c = a + b;
```

то компилятор выдаёт предупреждение `Order of volatile access is undefined in this statement`. Как я понимаю, это означает, что неизвестно, какая переменная первой загрузится в регистр общего назначения, и возможна такая ситуация, когда переменная `a` загрузилась в регистр, сработало прерывание, изменило это переменную, а основная программа продолжает работать со старым значением. Некоторые источники рекомендую в таких ситуациях разбивать выражение на части, например:

```
uint32_t c = a;
c += b;
```

но на мой взгляд, так мы лишь затыкаем компилятор, а не устраняем причину проблемы.

А теперь собственно вопрос. В программе обработчики прерываний постоянно периодически изменяют volatile-переменные, а основная программа выполняет математические преобразования. Как только пришло новое значение переменной, старое уже неинтересно. Можно ли в этом случае игнорировать предупреждение компилятора? Есть ли у этого предупреждения другие источники, о которых я не догадываюсь?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В языке С порядок доступа к `volatile` объектам, наряду с вызовами функций ввода-вывода, является частью *наблюдаемого поведения* (observable behavior) программы. Поэтому данное предупреждение просто выглядит как предупреждение от педантичного компилятора, который говорит, что наблюдаемое поведение программы в данном случае однозначно не определено.

Компилятор прав - оно действительно не определено однозначно. Но компилятор, разумеется, не знает, какие грани наблюдаемого поведения являются действительно важными для специфики вашей программы, а какие нет, и выдает абстрактное педантичное предупреждение.

Если в данном случае для вас порядок доступа к этим переменным действительно важен, тогда предупреждение вполне оправданно. Если же вы не видите проблем с любым возможным порядком доступа, то перепишите код чисто ради устранения предупреждения от компилятора.

Понятно, что в описанной вами ситуации, при модификации `a` и `b` из независимых линий исполнения (потоки, прерывания и т.п.) и при отсутствии какой-либо синхронизации, будет наблюдаться выраженный data race. А уж смертелен ли этот data race для вашего приложения - вам виднее. Если вы захотите избавиться от этого data race, то тут одним подавлением предупреждений не обойдешься - придется организовывать ту или иную форму синхронизации доступа к этой паре.

Answer (score 1):

> "но на мой взгляд, так мы лишь затыкаем компилятор, а не устраняем причину проблемы"

**Устранить причину проблемы в рамках языка программирования и компилятора вы не сможете в принципе** (на то и ключевое слово `volatile`), так что просто примите это предупреждение к сведению и сами решайте, насколько оно важно в конкретной задаче...

Answer (score 0):

> Как только пришло новое значение переменной, старое уже неинтересно.

У меня была аналогичная проблема. И я решал её приблизительно так:

```
volatile uint32_t a;
volatile uint32_t b;
uint32_t a1;
uint32_t b1;
uint32_t x
uint8_t  trust;
// Запоминаем исходные значения
a1=a;
b1=b;
// Выполняем расчёт нужного значения
 x = a1+b1;
// Проверяем, можно ли доверять этому значению
if ( (a == a1) && (b == b1) )
    trust = 1;
else
    trust = 0;
```

Я понимаю, что с точки зрения теории, это решение - далеко не идеальное. Понимаю, что будут ложные присвоения trust, но если достаточно только уверенности в том. что результат расчёта действительно соответствует ПАРЕ исходных значений, то это почти наверняка.  Не 100%, но такая гарантия лучше никакой. А вот если trust==0, то это почти на 100% защитит от ложных результатов.